# Blackberry - can we change theme using our application?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, themes, rim-4.5

Is it possible to change theme programatically using JDE 4.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=25966&query.id=376348#M25966) - there is no way to programatically change the theme